I want to have 8 light bulbs and 8 switches in the circuit. Any switch should be able to put all light bulbs on or off
All the bulbs can be put on/off by any of the switches.

This is easy these days with smart bulbs or smart switches or both.  Have you considered any smart devices?

More details please. Are they already installed? Have you access to the wiring? Can you post the current wiring diagram.

You want 8 switches to turn on a row of lights?    That sounds really crazy and overkill.

One way and not necessarily the best. Install a 3-way switch at your power source for the first switch. Run three wires or 3 conductor NB cable, two travelers and the neutral, to 6 4-way switches and to a 3-way switch as the last switch. Connect the travelers to the switches and splice the neutral through. From the last 3-way switch and the spliced through neutral, connect your load wires, the 8 lights wired in parallel. Wire and breaker sizes would depend on the light wattage.
